# irony: how come some things generate AST and some dont

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, irony

SQL sample just generates token tree

But most samples on how to use irony all go 'parse' then 'traverse generated ast'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AST is only generated if the `LanguageFlags.CreateAst` flag is set on the grammar.